# apache sqoop installation missing addtowar script

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I was installing apache sqoop for hadoop v1. in the installation it says script /bin/addtowar.sh  shoudl be in sqoop bin dir but i dont find it. 
used web url
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.1/Installation.html
Thanks!

Comment: I came across the same issue today...the addtowar.sh script is not present in bin directory....have you been able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think your missing this command: mv sqoop-(version)-bin-hadoop(hadoop version).tar.gz /usr/lib/sqoop

Please replace that command with this command:: mv sqoop-(version)-bin-hadoop(hadoop version) /usr/lib/sqoop

I think Your problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

addToWar.sh is no longer used in the install.

I ran into the same thing, and documented the solution here:

http://brianoneill.blogspot.com/2014/10/sqoop-1993-w-hadoop-2-installation.html